# How do I play a sound in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Sounds silly but Im having a heck of a time playing a .wav file in WP8. There does not seem to be a definitive, quick and easy guide on how to do this. i have the following code bit it crashes when I try to play the sound.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
MediaElement mp1 = new MediaElement();
mp1.Source = new Uri("Assets/audio/myfile.wav");
mp1.Play();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have these references..

```
using System.Windows.Resources;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
```

Now follow this step:

```
 StreamResourceInfo _stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/Assets/audio/myfile.wav", UriKind.Relative));
 SoundEffect _soundeffect = SoundEffect.FromStream(_stream.Stream);
 SoundEffectInstance soundInstance = _soundeffect.CreateInstance();
 FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
 soundInstance.Play();
```

Hope for success.

Comment: Thanks Dotnet. Unfortunately this does not work for me. I get the error: 'Error 1 The type or namespace name 'SoundEffect' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: Hi, you are missing a reference to "Microsoft.Xna.Framework" library that contains "SoundEffect" class. Please referenced to proper version of this library.